# Безусловно — вводное слово или наречие?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако риск потери инвестируемых денег **безусловно** увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.

Я не выделил запятыми слово «безусловно», что было засчитано как ошибка, но я с этим не до конца согласен. Предложение составлено двояко, ведь «безусловно» можно рассмотреть как наречие?

Answer (score 2):

При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако риск потери инвестируемых денег, **безусловно,** увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.

Э**то вводное слово по следующим признакам:**

1) возможна замена **другими вводными словами** (конечно, несомненно);

2) в роли наречия ***безусловно*** выступает там, где важна его семантика (**без условий, без ограничений**), а здесь нет речи о каких-либо условиях. **Здесь всё однозначно:** чем выше прибыль, тем выше риск.

3) часто наречие ***безусловно***  используется в сочетаниях с **прилагательными** (безусловно верный путь, безусловно порядочный человек);

4) **в сочетаниях с глаголами** наречие стоит на втором месте и на него падает ударение (он ему верил безусловно, верил во всём).

**Пример:**

Политический разум и революционное сознание пролетарских масс и их вождей указал им **безусловно верный путь** экономической политики». [Печать Западной Украины о процессе «промпартии» // «Правда», 1930]

Comment: Jasmin, благодарю. А можно ли как-то доказать, что это наречие? Какие-то аргументы можно привести?

Comment: В принципе можно. Надо сказать, что наречие "безусловно" здесь имеет  прямое значение (без условий, однозначно), а не значение "конечно, несомненно". Получится: "...риск потери инвестируемых денег однозначно  увеличивается..."